# mysql: sequence of executed queries

Tags: mysql, database

I have to update a row into a table(InnoDB) and then right after select the last registry that I updated and make an insert. If the connection is too slow(for the update statement), can the select statement get the wrong row? Assuming that I'm using two different queries.

Comment: Not if you use last_insert_id on an auto_incrementing primary key

Comment: Could you please show the queries you are using? It depends on how you are identifying the row you are updating/selecting.

Comment: Better, do it in a procedure.

Comment: @Strawberry - note that the first query is an UPDATE, not an INSERT, so last_insert_id does not apply.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please consider that to get better answers is always a good idea to post your code or all the details needed to answer!

Comment: @Vilx - Good point!! So, the OP already knows which id is being inserted. So, no problem

Comment: @Strawberry - not necessarily. Maybe he updates the row with the oldest date or something.

Comment: I'm not using last_insert_id. I'm just using the SELECT MAX(ID), after I updated, then make a new insert to the same table.

Comment: But MAX(ID) is meaningless in this context. If you're making a new insert, just use an auto_incrementing id. Even if MAX(ID) made sense somehow, it could only do so in the context of a transaction.

Comment: yes, I'm using auto increment, my app is working fine. The only doubt I have is if mysql will wait for the update complete before a new query is executed.

Comment: No. It won't. This is a bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using SQL to run your script or are you running it somewhere else? (ex PHP, Python, C#)

A Script from SQL should* always complete one line before moving on to the next but if you're unsure you could call something like the sleep function or the wait delay function to pause before you run your second line.

*I say should as I've seen some extremely rare random cases, usually with longer running queries that don't.  If your first job takes a long time to complete it may be worth the effort to schedule the first job in Job Agent, then later that day schedule the second job.

Comment: I'm executing the queries from PHP.

Comment: In most cases (unless you've already accounted for it in some way) PHP may not wait before one query is done executing before starting the next query. A quick and easy solution is to put your queries into a stored proc and run the stored proc instead.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL does not keep records of row insertion order. Any algorithm that's based on *last registry that I updated* must implement its own means to gather the required information. If it doesn't, it will get the wrong row sooner or later. (Network speed is probably not as relevant as concurrent access.)